# AngularJS with C# WCF Wait for record to insert before refreshing on screen

Tags: c#, angularjs, database, wcf, insert

I am new to AngularJS and building a webpage that has a history table. When an action happens an entry is made in the database using a $http.post. Afterwards I want to retrieve the data from the database again and display it back in the table to show the new entry of the history being logged.

The issue I am having is that the post is called first and then the get, but the get happens before the insert can complete. How do I delay, or prevent the call to get the new data from the history until the post has completed?

Here are the $http calls I am making:

```
$http.post('http://MYSERVER/Service1.svc/insertImageHistory', {params: {JSON: parameters}}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        console.log(data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        console.log(data);
    });

    $http.get('http://MYSERVER/WcfService/Service1.svc/getImageHistory', {params: {DOC_ID: DOC_ID}})
        .success(function (response){
                $scope.InsImageHistory = response;
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
           console.error('Response error', status, data);
        });
```

Comment: Need to provide more information.

Comment: I edited my post to add more detail, hopefully it makes more sense, let me know if I should add more clarifications. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more information on how you are posting your data to your end point (WCF API) would be helpful, but i'll assume you are making use of $http.

A basic http request in Angular looks like this:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function (response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
}, function (response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

As you can see in the above example, the $http service incorporates Promises. Once it receives a response from your WCF service request, it will hit the '.then' portion of the function. This allows you to run code after you receive a response from your Get/Post request.

You can include your code in the '.then' part of the request. This way when you receive a response back from the 'Insert' api method, you can be sure that the insert has completed, and you can call your 'refresh' GET api request thereafter.

Documentation for $http can be found here - [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
Documentation for Promises in angular $q can be found here - [Promises $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

**EDIT:** Okay now that I have some more information I can advise further.

If I was you, I would Create an angular Service/Factory to wrap your functionality (Object Oriented Design). You can call it "ImageService". Create Functions such as Add, Get, Delete etc Which will wrap your $http methods.

I have created a really quick and simple Plunker for you here to see what I'm talking about: [Angular Promises Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/H4ixEdElWneivpEdx6q4?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Angular and this looks like what I need. I edited my original post to hopefully make more sense. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from people on this site, I figured out how to make it work now. I changed my code to use .then for my first $http.post and inside the .then I called the #http.get like so:

```
$http.post('http://MYSERVER/Service1.svc/insertImageHistory', {params: {JSON: parameters}})
    .then(function(data, status) {
       $http.get('http://MYSERVER/WcfService/Service1.svc/getImageHistory', {params: {DOC_ID: DOC_ID}})
        .success(function (response){
                $scope.InsImageHistory = response;
                //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
           console.error('Response error', status, data);
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: That will definitely do the trick, however its not best practice to nest your $http calls inside one another. If you want your application to become scale-able, you should make use of Services, Factories, and Controllers. See my Plunker example for some direction